# How to know a UIComponent width at runtime?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, width, uicomponents

I have a UIComponent which is a simple view (I narrowed the problem).
Here is the xib and class :

[image]

Then I put this component in a view in the storyboard, sets its constraints:

[image]

So normally the red rectangle has different width value depending on the device width.

This is the case graphically, the component resizes itself correctly, but when I call the function to print its width, the result is always the same, whatever the device that launch the app.

In fact, the value is always the actual width of the component in the storyboard.

This is so weird.
Is there a way to know the actual width of the UIComponent ?

Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: How are the constraints configured?

Comment: @Eric - What is the value it's printing out for `print(self.frame.width)`? Is it showing any value, or returning zero? How exactly did you set the `NSLayoutConstraint` values for the `StatBarView`? Did you set them to have a width that's relative or equal it it's superview, or are the left and right sides constrained to the left and right edges of it's superview?

Comment: The StatBarView has height fixes, centered vertically, and left and right sides constrained to superview. The value printed is the StatBarView width of the storyboard, which does not correspond to the width at runtime. For example if I set iPhone SE in the storyboard, the width is 239 pixels, and this value is used even when I execute on an iPhone 7 plus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use layoutIfNeeded() on your view after setting up the constraints but before trying to get its width. Constraints are not applied right at the moment of activation

(sorry for 2 answers ^^ they're just too different)

Answer (score 1):

It is better not to use both constraints and frames for mark up simultaneously. Stick to constraints and make a new constraint for width of each element. Each element's width should be related to parent view's width via multiplier.

For instance you should make something like this

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: element, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: parentView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0)
```

to make an element occupy 50% of its parentView width

Then if you want to change it you should replace the old constraint with a new one with new desired multiplier of course. Such a shuffle with replacing exists because multiplier property is get only

And by the way my answer was for the case if you want to change % of width occupied by every element inside your component. If propotions are the same all the time (50% 25% 25%)  you do not need to change the constraint if your component changes its size. All elements related to component's size constraints will change their size as well (if you change component's size via constraints)

Comment: Thanks for your help @Pavel. Tried to implement this line in the setter of my variables, but it crashes with a "View hierarchy unprepared for constraint". Anyway, the subviews resize when I set the percentage value, but it's calculated with the parent's width which is not correct. That's my problem. I don't understand why `self.frame.width `doesn't get the value at runtime but gets the value from the storyboard (which furthermore I didn't set as a constraint !)